# Having trouble in changing the image opacity

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class Form1

    Public Shared Function SetImgOpacity(ByVal imgPic As Image, ByVal imgOpac As Single) As Image

        Dim bmpPic As New Bitmap(imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height)
        Dim gfxPic As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPic)
        Dim cmxPic As New ColorMatrix()
        Dim iaPic As New ImageAttributes()

        cmxPic.Matrix33 = imgOpac

        iaPic.SetColorMatrix(cmxPic, ColorMatrixFlag.[Default], ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
        gfxPic.DrawImage(imgPic, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmpPic.Width, bmpPic.Height), 0, 0, imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, iaPic)

        gfxPic.Dispose()
        iaPic.Dispose()

        Return bmpPic

    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim a As Image = bmpPic.Image
        SetImgOpacity(a, 50)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click the button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: you may want to change the headline to your question to be more specific, every question on the site could come under you current headline

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Is bmpPic.Image an actual, instantiated object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to set the `bmpPic.Image` to the value returned from your function.

Something like

```
Dim a As Image = bmpPic.Image         
bmpPic.Image = SetImgOpacity(a, 50)
```

Comment: LOL, I for got to type it there :P, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the color matrix values range from `0` to `1`, so you should probably use `0.5` instead of `50`.